# Factorial series with ratio test inconclusive

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to determine the convergence of this series:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2n! \over (n+3)! }$

The ratio test gives 1, so I don't know how to solve it. Wolfram alpha suggests me to use the comparison test, but which series should I compare it with?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suppose $2n!$ means $(2n)!$?

Comment: @Bernard - WHY do you suppose that? Ratio test giving 1 suggests the OP's notation is correct.

Comment: @Bernard Is left-multiplication having precedence over factorial a standard convention? For instance, usage on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Trigonometric.2C_inverse_trigonometric.2C_hyperbolic.2C_and_inverse_hyperbolic_functions) and [Wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cosine.html) suggests the answer is "No".

Comment: That's also my convention, but one never knows whether there's a typo.

Comment: @Bernard, You said "I SUPPOSE" something means something else - that is not simply checking for a typo, it is ASSUMING there is a typo. Also in general you are right, one never knows, but the OP's comment about the ratio test gives a pretty clear clue he meant what he said.

Comment: I meant $\frac{1}{n^2}$ but you already had an answer with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant what you wrote (it seems everyone else assumes the opposite), and $2 n!$ means just that, 2 times $n!$. This is consistent with you finding that the ratio of successive terms has limit 1. Not sure why everyone else assumes you don't know what you are talking about and answers a different problem.

Your terms are of the form $\frac 2 {(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$. Each term is, for example, $\le \frac 1 {(n+1)(n+2)}$, which gives you the series to compare with. And this series is a telescoping series, making it easy to see it converges.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+4)!}\frac{(n+3)!}{(2n)!}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n+4}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

and thus the series diverges

If you menat $\;2\cdot n!\;$ , then

$$\frac{2n!}{(n+3)!}=\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\le\frac2{n^2}$$

and by the comparison test the series *converges*

Comment: My book and Wolfram Alpha say that the series converges..

Comment: @Vitto Then either you miscopied the series or both your book and WA are wrong. Observe that I considered the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{n+3)!}$$ I added now an argument in case you meant $\;2\cdot n!\;$ in the numerator.

Comment: The literal interpretation of @mathguy was correct, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Vitto Anytime. Observe that Bernard asked you about the interpretation almost 25 minutes ago and you didn't address his doubt.

Comment: By the way, is left-multiplication having precedence over factorial a standard convention? For instance, usage on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Trigonometric.2C_inverse_trigonometric.2C_hyperbolic.2C_and_inverse_hyperbolic_functions) and [Wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cosine.html) suggests the answer is "No".

Comment: Where I grew up (Eastern Europe) the convention is, indeed, that the factorial has precedence. In computing (programming), unary operations like the factorial have precedence over binary operations like multiplication; that is a perfectly reasonable convention, which is followed in most of the world. Parentheses never hurt though, even where not needed, example: $2(n!)$. WITH THAT SAID, the OP made a comment about the ratio test which gave a strong clue.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, you can do this summation!
$$\frac{2n!}{(n+3)!}=\frac2{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}$$
So
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{2n!}{(n+3)!}&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\frac16+\sum_{n=2}^N\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac1{(N+2)(N+3)}-\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\frac16-\frac1{(N+2)(N+3)}\end{align}$$
So
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n!}{(n+3)!}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac16-\frac1{(N+2)(N+3)}\right)=\frac16$$
And so it converges.

Answer (score -1):

$$\dfrac{T_{m+1}}{T_m}=\dfrac{2(m+1)!}{(m+1+3)!}\cdot\dfrac{(m+3)!}{(2m)!}=\dfrac{(2m+2)(2m+1)}{m+4}=\dfrac{(2m+2)(2+1/m)}{1+4/m}$$

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\dfrac{T_{m+1}}{T_m}=?$$

Comment: Why did you wrote (2m+1)! in Tm instead of 2m! ?

Comment: @Vitto, Thanks for yours observation. Rectified the typo.